# didUpdateHeading not Called

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to use compass for update Heading . But my  didUpdateHeading not called . I am newer in iOS . Please help any help would be apperciated.

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager     *locationManager;
locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.delegate=self;
    //Start the compass updates.

    [locationManager startUpdatingHeading];

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading
{
    NSLog(@"New magnetic heading: %f", newHeading.magneticHeading);
    NSLog(@"New true heading: %f", newHeading.trueHeading);
}
```

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: There is a known issue with it not working on the simulator

Answer (score 2):

The code you provided (assuming you haven't changed anything when pasting here) is missing a function or a code of block to run the first part, I suggest you put it in your `viewController` init, like so:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {        
         locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
         locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
         locationManager.delegate=self;
         //Start the compass updates.

         [locationManager startUpdatingHeading];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: didUpdateToLocation method call but didUpdateHeading never call

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot delegate in .h flie `<CLLocationManagerDelegate>`

Comment: it is already added in the @interface, doesn't matter what file you put it in

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for authorization for using location? You need to use

```
[locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
```

or

```
[locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
```